# Binding Custom object to Checkbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to bind a checkbox to a custom object boolean property as follows:

```
chkTableIsReadonly.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Checked", objectBindingSource, "ApplyforVisa", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
```

The custom class supports the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Everything works find when I initially bind the checkbox to a new object:

`objectBindingSource.Datasource = new objectToBindTo`

Here is the odd part:

1. If I check the box, the property Set gets called and the INotifyPropertyChanged event gets called and everyone is happy.
2. If I uncheck the same box, the property Set doesn't get called, the INotifyPropertyChanged event never gets called and (the worse part), I cannot navigate to another record.

I have tried capturing the CheckedChanged event to set the object.ApplyForVisa property manually, but no success. The property Set gets called and the INotifyPropertyChanged event gets called, but I am still locked on control and can't navigate.

I have tried calling bindingsource.endedit in the CheckedChanged event, no success.

It only matters if I uncheck the box. The checkbox is two-state - true or false.

All of my other bindings work just fine - text boxes, combo boxes, datagrid. Just not checkbox.

My only thought is that is seems to act like a binding source data error, but no error is thrown. If I add the data error event handler for the binding source, it never gets called.

Comment: Can you include code for your `objectToBindTo` implementation including the `ApplyForVisa` property, as well as any attached handlers to `PropertyChanged` for the instance?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `ApplyForVisa` property is a Boolean, you can just fix this by setting `formattingEnabled` parameter for the `Binding` to False.

```
chkTableIsReadonly.DataBindings.Add( _
    New Binding("Checked", objectBindingSource, "ApplyforVisa", _
                False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, False))
```